# Electron nsis-web installer uninstalls existing app while installing update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, nsis, electron-builder

We are facing an issue in Electron app, wherein the existing app is getting deleted while trying to install a new version (a similar kind of issue, (#[2381](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2381)). In our case, it's not just links in the start menu but seems the entire app itself is getting uninstalled, as we see the app folder (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs) itself is getting emptied during installation. So, we need to install it twice every time (as a temporary workaround).

**App Details:**

Electron Builder Version: v22.14.13

Electron Version: 17.0.0

node: 14.16.0

Operating System: Windows

I am not sure what is wrong.

**Build Config :**

[image]

Comment: Can you share the Nsis script?

Comment: hi @Slappy, question has been updated with build config.

Comment: @Slappy All electron installers use the same .nsi based on template data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the reason. The issue was due to both `productName` and `artifactName` are same in the build config. Changing (OR adding a suffix to) the `artifactName`, has fixed the issue.

*Note: I'm not sure whether it should work fine even if both `productName` and `artifcatName` are same, but in our case, it caused
an issue.*

**New Build Config in my project as follows:**

[image]

Comment: You are a genious and the Electron builder team should update this issue or add to the docs. Insane how such a small thing can have such a breaking impact